# How to highlight the message for which a notification is sent to Microsoft Teams activity feed from external source

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

In Microsoft teams, whenever we click on a notification received in the activity feed, the context is always highlighted for which the notification was sent.

I am trying to achieve the same for the notification that I am sending, but unable to find a way.

I am sending a proactive message from a teams bot in C#, with message.TeamsNotifyUser() enabled.

With this, I am able to receive the notification in the activity feed, but whenever I click on that notification, nothing is highlighted, and I just land on the chat screen.

Comment: Hi @Divya, sorry for the delayed response. Are you using Bot mention to notify users?

Comment: Hi @Divya, are you still facing the issue, could you please let us the current state.

Answer (score 0):

This is two step process.

1.Getting notification by [subscribing to new channel messages](https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/evergreen-assets/safelinks/1/atp-safelinks.html) - [Sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#code-samples)

2.[Sending proactive notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet) as reply to new message using Bot . - [Sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet#references)